# You can keep it only after you give it to someone else. What is it?

Tags: riddle

You can keep it only after you give it to someone else. What is it?

Comment: .......happiness

Comment: Friendship​‌‍​‌‍?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer to the riddle is:

> your word

Comment: You beat me to it by a few seconds. :)

Comment: cant accept it yet, you were too fast ;) Or maybe the riddle is just too easy

Comment: Haha I assumed someone else would have a quick answer.  It's a good one though, I saw it before though unfortunately

Answer (score 5):

Or, (equivalently),

> a promise.

Comment: You don't give that, you make it. (In my dialect, at least.)

Comment: Over to the language stackexchange!

Answer (score 4):

Answer

> Genes
>
>  You can keep your genes "going", only after you passed them you your son/daughter.

Comment: You can keep it ONLY after you give it to someone else

Comment: @Marc. I know. I forced it a little. I was trying to be creative and come up with a different answer from the ones already listed

Answer (score 4):

Less seriously :

> The new awesome video game that your wife doesn't really want for her birthday :D

Comment: Cute. But while you *can* give that away, and yet keep it, you could also just keep it — you don't need to give it away.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible answer:

> Illicit earnings

because:

> Gaining a large amount of money from dubious sources can attract the attention of law enforcement agencies, who won't let you keep the money if they figure out that you earned it illegally. In order to keep the money, you have launder it. A common way of laundering money is giving it to someone (e.g. your wife) who's running an apparently legitimate business (e.g. a car wash). This person will mix this dirty money in with legitimate transactions, so it will ultimately appear as profit, which you can then keep since you happen to be the owner of this business.

Comment: Or you use it in small batches in places that clearly won't ask. you can still just keep it though

Comment: A car wash, huh? Or maybe a internet fund to help you pay for your chemotherapy bills?

Answer (score -1):

> The Message of Hope and the Promise of Freedom from addiction.-AA, NA 12steps

Comment: Welcome to [puzzling.se]! Please use `>!` to hide your intended solution behind a spoiler.

Answer (score -4):

> Grace and Forgiveness, given by God to be shared by you!